# CakePHP 3.0 bin/cake command not found

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm coming to CakePHP from Codeigniter. I started a new project and installed CakePHP 3.0 using Composer into a Ubuntu Vagrant machine I use for development.

I'm trying to create a DB Migration but it seems the bin/cake console isnt working for me.

I can't find anything in the docs about setting up bin/cake, I also tried setting the cake script as executable.... no joy.

All I get is either "permission denied", if I then run as sudo i get "Command not found".

Any help appreciated,

Comment: what you get with `ls -l bin/`

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant www-data 1352 Jul 30 13:40 cake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant www-data  955 Jul 30 13:40 cake.bat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant www-data 1218 Jul 30 13:40 cake.php

Answer (score 17):

your current permission mask is 664, executable bit is missing.

try:

```
chmod 755 bin/cake
```

Comment: OK, I applied that in the Vagrant box.... but it didn't work, it did however change the permissions on my OSX side. I must be missing something on the Vagrant side? I applied it using Sudo whilst SSH inot Vagrant machine

Comment: Besides the permission issue, use `./`, ie `./bin/cake`, otherwise `$PATH` will be looked up instead of the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's how i fixed it.

Turns out the version of vagrant I'm using doesn't allow file permission changes from the terminal it has to be done in the vagrant file. So i just set the file permission setting in the vagrant file to 755 and voila!

Thanks for the help.